# Почему санитайзера нет под mingw?

Tags: mingw

Компилирую программу и получаю ошибку

`undefined reference to '__asan_init'`

и ещё много таких же с __asan. Погуглив в интернете решил попробовать в Linux и там всё собралось и запустилось. А в windows нет. Версия компилятора 8.1.0.

Comment: Потому что "ASAN is not available for Windows".

Comment: Где написано, и почему. Официально есть список причин?

Comment: На сайте MinGW-w64 и в github-репозитории ASan. Потому что никто не разрабатывал подобную библиотеку под Windows, а портирование существующей или слишком трудоёмко или вовсе невозможно в связи с разительной разницей в работе операционных систем.